# Proof that a hypersurface with non-negative normal everywhere is globally a graph

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

**Note:** This is essentially a streamlined version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477714/proof-that-a-leaf-of-a-foliation-is-globally-a-graph), asked a short while ago. I am hoping the reason it received no responses is because it was too convoluted (as opposed to being too obvious).

Specifically, if I have an $(n-1)$-dimensional (smooth) submanifold $M$ of $R^n_{++}$ (the strictly positive orthant of $n$-dimensional Euclidean space), and I know that the normal to the tangent plane at each point of $M$ is non-negative with at least one coordinate (say the last) always strictly positive, does it follow that, globally, $M$ is the graph of a function $f: D \rightarrow R$, for some domain $D$ in $R^{n-1}$? By the graph of $f$ I mean of course that $M = \{ x \in D : (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}))$.

I have various results that state when such a manifold is globally a graph but they all require that, $(x^0_1,\ldots,x^0_{n-1},r),\; r > 0$ intersect $M$ only once (here $(x^0_1,\ldots,x^0_{n-1})$ is strictly positive). As I mentioned in the other question, I'm pretty sure this is true and the reason is that otherwise the normal would have to turn negative (as, say, with $S^1$ in $R^2$). But I can't seem to extend it to the case $n > 2$.

Any "leads" would be appreciated, including just giving me hints for the $n=3$ case that I can extend.